# I'm stuck in proving this statement of division

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

Can anyone help me prove if n divides a and n divides b, then n divides (ax + by).

I'm not sure if writing in the form of :
a = nx and b = ny are still allowed to be used as x and y exists in the definition of the conclusion.
I was thinking of using other variables such as: a = nc, and b = nd but I got stuck instead.

Comment: And so... if $a=nc$ and $b=nd$, then $ax+by = \dots$ where you make the replacements you suggested...

Comment: $\frac{a}{n}$ and $\frac{b}{n}$ then $\frac{ax}{n}+\frac{by}{n}$

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ divides $a$ then $a=nc$.  If $n$ divides $b$ then $b=nd$.

So $ax+by=ncx+ndy=n(cx+dy)$, so $n $ divides $ax+by$.